# send notification to parent when child enters or exit geofence

Tags: android, android-geofence

i have 2 type of end users of my android Family Locator application. 1 is parent and other is child. i want to know is there any way that when child's android mobile enters or exits the Geo fence (already created), notification should appear on parent's android mobile, not on child's own mobile. Please give suggestions.
Thank you in advance

Comment: you should have a backend for that, the child's mobile should send a message for the backend, and the backend can send a notification for the parent mobile

Comment: do you mean web services...?

Comment: yes, the mobile communicate with the backend through webservices

Comment: please explain a little bit

Comment: first creat a backend where you have "the matches" from parents and childs, and maybe some registration in the apps to be more secure.

the child will be sending messages (through webservices) with the position, in the backend you will see if the child is inside the geofence, if its not inside it will send a push notification to the parent mobile

Comment: yes i have already written web services and login for this app

Comment: right. thank you dear for your help. it was really very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use push notifications to achieve this. When the child enters or exit the geofence receives the notification and then the child app sends a request to a backend. Then when the backend receives this notification identifies who is the parent of this child based on the information sent and then it can send a push notification to the parent app.

If you don't want to implement a backend for this, you could try using this service that has SDK for Android and iOS:

[Parse](https://www.parse.com/)